# Only Show Time From DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have my `DateTime` field formatted as I need, but the issue I have is that I can not figure out a way to **ONLY** show the `Time` element of the field.

Here is syntax I use

```
DateTime? fmtTimeOfDeparture;
string TimeOfDeparture = null;

IFormatProvider format = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
fmtTimeOfDeparture = DateTime.ParseExact((TimeOfDeparture != null ? TimeOfDeparture : null), "HHmmss", format);

Console.WriteLine(fmtTimeOfDeparture);
```

Which will write this to the console:

```
01/11/2017 6:49:00 PM
```

I **ONLY** want it to show

```
6:49:00 PM
```

How should the syntax be updated to only show this?

Comment: So just do this: `Console.WriteLine(fmtTimeOfDeparture.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));`. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: I would try 'fmtTimeOfDeparture.Value.ToShortTimeString()' which is the answer I found by searching for this question.

Comment: @Icemanind - that produces an error of Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: @JamesJayson - that produces an error of 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @MichaelMormon Sorry, didn't notice it was a nullable. Try this:`Console.WriteLine(fmtTimeOfDeparture.Value.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));`.

Comment: @Icemanind - that gives an error of 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @MichaelMormon - Make sure you are using `fmtTimeOfDeparture` and not `TimeOfDeparture`. `fmtTimeOfDeparture` is a nullable DateTime. It should not be giving you an error saying `string does not contain...`

Comment: @Icemanind - still showing a date element when printed to console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another formatting for converting datetime to string

```
DateTime? fmtTimeOfDeparture;
string TimeOfDeparture = "01/11/2017 6:49:00 PM";

IFormatProvider format = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
fmtTimeOfDeparture = DateTime.ParseExact((TimeOfDeparture ?? DateTme.Now.ToString()), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", format);

Console.WriteLine($"{fmtTimeOfDeparture:h:mm:ss tt}");
```

Comment: That still writes the date element.

Comment: @MichaelMormon are you sure? btw why your string is null?

Comment: It reads from an API - and sets the variable equal to the value from the API, so there is a possibility it could be null

Comment: What do you want to put instead if string was null? I put Datetime.Now....  See the operatpr `??` will assign Datetime.Now.ToString if your string is null.

Answer (score 0):

try using string.trim to remove the date for alternative solution if the time format isn't working for you

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime? fmtTimeOfDeparture = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(fmtTimeOfDeparture.HasValue ? fmtTimeOfDeparture.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `IFormatProvider` if you are going to write it in the format `6:49:00 PM`?

All you need is this:

```
DateTime? fmtTimeOfDeparture;

if( fmtTimeOfDeparture.HasValue ) {
   Console.WriteLine( fmtTimeOfDeparture.Value.ToString( "h:mm:ss tt" ) );
}
```

Obviously it will not write anything because `fmtTimeOfDeparture` is null as you have it.